# problem in printing floating point

Tags: floating-point, printf, iar

hi I am using IAR c compiler, I am trying to print floating point value like

```
printf("version number: %f\n",1.4);
```

but I am always getting like below in console

```
version number:ERROR
```

help please
thanks in advance
kudi

Answer (score 2):

The error is probably due to your dlib configuration. Because of the focus on embedded targets with resource restrictions the behaviour/feature set of the iar c library (dlib) is configurable.

Look at Project/Options/General Options/Library Options.

From the docs:

*CHOOSING PRINTF FORMATTER
The printf function uses a formatter called _Printf. The default version is quite
large, and provides facilities not required in many embedded applications. To reduce the
memory consumption, three smaller, alternative versions are also provided in the
standard C/EC++ library.*

The #define _DLIB_PRINTF_SPECIFIER_FLOAT is available if printf knows floats.

Answer (score -1):

The format string for the `printf` function can specify floating point representations with a more explicit string:

```
printf("version number: %3.1f\n", 1.4);
```

I think this is the cause of the error message.

The '%3.1f' tells printf to use 3 characters, with one *after* the decimal place. The output should be

```
version number: 1.4
```

**EDIT:** Kudi, it seems the printf() function in the IAR compiler is quite different from the K&R printf() function.

[This link](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/usenet/embedded/show/78632-1.php) is just one example which leads me to think that my copy of K&R is going to be no help at all. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks for fast replay ,i tried what u said the output was like below
version_number:ERROR1f

Comment: I noticed that you said IAR c compiler. I was referring to 'The C Programming Language' by Kernighan and Ritchie. Maybe there's some difference in syntax. Actually, looking at that very old book, it's not clear that %3.1f would be acceptable. I suggest you go back to just %f and leave out the \n